# Excel : Add Border Top on Cell....

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, radgridview

I am exporting my `radgridview` to `excel`. my problem is how can I add a border top on a cell... I am really new to this so please bear with me...

I have tried using this code `.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = 1d;` but still can't do the `bordertop` on excel cell.....

thanks in advance.

```
        foreach (GridViewSummaryRowInfo item in gridviewID.MasterView.SummaryRows)
        {
            objexcelapp.Cells[lastRow + 3, 4] = item.Cells[item.Index + 4].Value.ToString();
            objexcelapp.Cells[lastRow + 3, 5] = item.Cells[item.Index + 5].Value.ToString();
            objexcelapp.Cells[lastRow + 3, 4].Font.Bold = true;
            objexcelapp.Cells[lastRow + 3, 5].Font.Bold = true;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
Excel.Range cell = range.Cells[1][1];
Excel.Borders border = cell.Borders;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle =
   Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle =
   Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle =
    Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle =
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```